# Entity retrieval filter

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-roo

I have entities that are localized and I would like to implement a language filter.

```
@Entity
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaEntity
@RooJpaActiveRecord
public class MyEntityI18n {

    @Column(columnDefinition = "text")
    @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = MyEntity.class)
    private MyEntity backedEntity;

    @NotNull    
    private String languageCode;

    @NotNull
    @Length(min=3, max=60)
    private String name;

}
```

Is there a way to set an always present filter which will add additional condition on the languageCode field whenever entities are being retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using activeRecord pattern, you could push in the relevant methods:

- findAllXxxx
- findXxxxEntries
- countXxxx
- findXxxx

Otherwise you could use an entityManager interceptor, or you could use a jpa repository instead of activeRecord pattern.